# How to add a "replace" button on each item of my JQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-button

I was wondering how I could put a button on each item in my JQuery sortable.  Right now I have a button on the top of the screen that adds the user input in the autocomplete to the sortable.  Here is my .js code that adds new items to my sortable:

```
$(".addButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // set var item to be the string inputted by the user
    var item = $("input[name='inputItem']").val(); //where 'inputItem' is the name of the <form> which contains the <input>
    // parses input string, splitting at commas into liArray containing substrings as elements
    var liArray = item.split(", ");
    // for loop to add each brew to the sortable list (length-1 because last element in array is empty string)
    for (var i = 0; i < liArray.length-1; i++) {
        // sets var $li to the string in the ith index of liArray
        var $li = $("<li class='ui-state-default'/>").text(liArray[i]);

        // adds var $li to gui
        $("#sortable").append($li);
    };

    $("#sortable").sort();

    // refreshes the page so var $li shows up
    $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
});
```

My idea was to add something like

```
<button>Button!</button>
```

to the this line:

```
var $li = $("<li class='ui-state-default'/>").text(liArray[i]);
```

But I dont know how to implement it exactly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("<li class='ui-state-default'/>").text(liArray[i]).append('<button>Button!</button>');
```